# laravel 5.2 return datatables and assign db field value before passing to blade

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

i have a function will return a datatables json, but the $type need to be set before passing to blade. I want to assign the each row result 'type' to $type, how can i do that? It needs to assign first so the blade can translate the value.

```
public function data() {

    $vendor_id = $this->getVendorId ();

    $menu = Menu::with('meal')->find($vendor_id);
    $meal = $menu->meal;


    return Datatables::of($meal)
    -> edit_column('type', '{{trans(\'admin/meal.'.$type.'\')}}')
    //-> edit_column('type', '<a href="#" >'.trans('admin/meal.' . $type).'</a>')
    -> edit_column('name', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/project/\' . $id ) }}}" >{{$name}}</a>')
    -> add_column('actions', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/meal/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm iframe" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  {{ Lang::get("admin/modal.edit") }}</a>
                <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/meal/\' . $id . \'/delete\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger iframe"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> {{ Lang::get("admin/modal.delete") }}</a>
                <input type="hidden" name="row" value="{{$id}}" id="row">')

    -> remove_column('id')
    -> remove_column('created_at')
    -> remove_column('vendor_id')       
    -> make();


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trans() function, is a helper function that can be called in the class herself, something like:

```
public function data() {

...

return Datatables::of($meal)
->editColumn('type', function($item) {
            return trans('admin/meal.'.$item->type); 
})
...
```

I dont know if is that what you mean.